# Open div on click (stay open)

Tags: css, html, click

I created this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RStBL/6/

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="value">1</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.main {
    width:50px;
    position:relative;
    background:lightgreen;
}
.box {
    text-align:center;
}
.menu {
    display:none;
}
.box:active + .menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

When I click this box, it opens for a second and disappears. The desired behavior is for it to stay open.

Does anybody have some advice?

Comment: What is open, what is hide? i didnt see any action in your fiddle.

Comment: When you stay pressed on the div

Comment: where is your script ? edit your fiddle and put new link to working fiddle

Comment: why script? dont use js

Comment: well, i click & hold in for 1 min in chrome. and nothing happen.

Comment: In html, css there is no click to open.

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript you have to use [the checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one:

add
`<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">`
and `<label for="check"></label>`

And here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RStBL/8/)